# API to detect usb device

Tags: c++, c, device-driver, linux-device-driver

Can some one please point to any API or links where i can detect a USB device and other interfaces to  transfer data into it.I am trying to do this on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) - it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see your device in the command output `lsusb`? If yes, then you must check the vendor Id and Product Id of the same.

Probably in Linux there is already a driver available to make bulk data transfer from concerned USB device (your USB device).

You can check this (http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) to verify whether a driver is available or not.

To make your own program and API's, as stated above `libusb` is a place to start, if you don't want to write a driver for your device.